# How to perform a PCA analysis for multiple bands from landsat data in python?

Tags: python, pca, landsat

I want to create a PCA of 5 landsat bands to detect change. I know how to do with arcgis but I can find a solution in python (jupyter Notebook). 
I have a dataarray with all my bands varibale and lon and lat. Then I create one array with all my bands (using np.dstack((dataset_1984.blue, etc.)). End after that I don't know how to proceed. Some help will be very very useful.

```
stacked = np.dstack((dataset_1984.blue,dataset_1984.green,dataset_1984.red,dataset_1984.nir,dataset_1984.swir1))
```

that create:

```
array([[[ 348,  502,  397, 2974, 1370],
        [ 348,  502,  397, 2974, 1370],
        [ 368,  502,  397, 3270, 1370],
        ..., 
        [ 603,  887,  843, 3121, 2082],
        [ 603,  887,  843, 3121, 2082],
        [ 738, 1172, 1380, 2364, 2456]],

       [[ 369,  544,  471, 2889, 1399],
        [ 388,  627,  507, 3354, 1833],
        [ 388,  627,  507, 3354, 1833],
        ..., 
        [ 680, 1009, 1165, 2575, 2715],
        [ 680, 1009, 1165, 2575, 2715],
        [ 757, 1172, 1416, 2279, 2743]],
```

and then:

```
data = stacked - np.mean(stacked, axis=0)
data.shape
(353, 588, 5)
```

Comment: Stating what the desired output is _will be very very useful._

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

You could use [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) for this task:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(data)  
PCA(copy=True, iterated_power='auto', n_components=2, random_state=None, svd_solver='auto', tol=0.0, whiten=False)
```

After doing that, one of the methods mentioned [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) will help you to visualize this data or infer further information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! when I try your script I have the error: 
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.

Comment: You might have to change the dimension of your input array first by doing the following: nsamples, nx, ny = train_dataset.shape
d2_train_dataset = train_dataset.reshape((nsamples,nx*ny))

Comment: Thx now it s working but when I look to the explained variance ratio I don't have the same value that I have after the process in arcgis. I have done somethink wrong I think before the PCA. If you have an explanation with pleasure or a code for landsat data using PCA! thx again